# Store and retrieve hashmap in Couchbase

Tags: hashmap, couchbase, sql++

Can I store a hashmap in couchbase. if I can, how to retrieve data through n1ql

Comment: Is it a right way for what?

Answer (score 1):

Couchbase at its heart is a key-value store, which behaves very much like a hash map. You can use N1QL to insert or upsert items, e.g.,

```
INSERT INTO my_bucket_name (KEY, VALUE) VALUES ( "key1", "raw value");
```

or

```
INSERT INTO my_bucket_name (KEY, VALUE) VALUES ( "key2", 12345);
```

or

```
INSERT INTO my_bucket_name (KEY, VALUE) VALUES ( "key3", {"field1": "value"});
```

To retrieve any of the documents you would use a N1QL query like:

```
SELECT * FROM default USE KEYS "key1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase supports a number of datastructures, including a Java Map.  The stored data is backed by JSON, so you can use it with N1QL.  See the [documentation on datastructures](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.6/sdk/java/datastructures.html) for more info.